# Adding element to an empty JSON object - Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have an empty JSON object

```
export class Car {}
```

I have imported it in a `component.ts` and I would like to add some fields in a loop. Something like

```
aux = new Car;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 car.addName("name" + i);
}
```

My goal would be to get at the end the following object

```
car: {
  name1: name1;
  name2: name2;
  ....
}
```

I have created the JSON object empty because at the beginning I do not know how many elements or fields will have. I could create this object by javascript. I do not need to have an `export class`

is it possible?

Comment: Cant use the same key twice in an object, could have an array of objects tho...

Comment: sorry, typo. I m gonna update it

Comment: What is the relationship between `Car` and `ImportParameter`? You're not using the second one at all in your component

Comment: What is `car`? What is `aux`? Are they properties of `ImportParameter` class?

Comment: Sorry. That was also a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add properties like this

```
aux = new Car;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  aux["name" + i] = "name"+i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could create this object by javascript. I do not need to have an export class

Yes it is possible.

**Working Demo**

```js
var car = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 car["name" + (i+1)] = "name" + (i+1);
}

console.log(car);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you define a class for an empty object? In any case, define an interface:

```
export interface Car {
     [id: string]: string
}
```

Now, to fill it:

```
const car = <Car>{};

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    car[`name${i}`] = `name${i}`;
}
```